# Derivative of a Matrix equation

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-calculus

I am working on fitting a model using gradient descent. My initial equation is:

$MSE = \frac{1} {N} \sum^N_{i=1} (M_i - \theta*P_{i-1} - K * Y_i))^2$.

$M$ and $P$ are $5$ by $N$ matrices, $\theta$ is 5 by 5, $K$ is 5 by 96, and $Y$ is 96 by $N$.

I want to take the derivative of this with respect to $K$. I get:

$\frac{dMSE}{dK} = \frac{2} {N} \sum^N_{i=1} (-M_i + \theta*P_{i-1} + K * Y_i))(Y_i)^T$.

Can someone tell me if this is correct and if it isn't what I did wrong?

Comment: Yes, and it looks even nicer without the summation (and a re-indexed $P$)
$$\large{\frac2n\left(KY+\theta P-M\right)Y^T}$$

Comment: Okay so this might be a dumb question, but why are you able to just drop the summation? In the original MSE equation, could you also drop the summation? I'm coding it into python, and I get a different answer with/without the summation, so how do you know when you can omit it?

Comment: There's no need for an explicit summation.
The MSE can be written as
$$
\large{\frac1n\;\;\operatorname{Trace}\left(\left(KY+\theta P-M\right)^T\left(KY+\theta P-M\right)\right)}
$$

Comment: So why do you need to add the Trace to the MSE to remove the summation, but you don't for the other equation? Thank you so much, my linear algebra is just really rusty

Comment: The MSE is scalar-valued (just like the trace function). The gradient is matrix-valued, so it must be a matrix expression (and the trace cannot produce that kind of value).